# System.AccessViolationException in C# interface to Swi-prolog

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, swi-prolog

I am new here and I hope that i will find a solution for my problem. The background of the problem is as follows:

- I am trying to build an expert system that constitute a C# front-end which is interacting with Swi-prolog.
- I have downloaded `SwiPlCs.dll` (A CSharp class library to connect .NET languages with Swi-Prolog)
- And added a reference to it in a Visual Studio project(Win form app) that I have created to test if I can query prolog from c# (I followed the example used in the documentation found [here](http://www.lesta.de/prolog/swiplcs/Generated/Index.aspx)).
- It worked fine.
- Then, in a more complicated scenario, I have built a WCF service that will act as an intermediary layer between Swi-Prolog and C# client application (it consumes the service).
- The service is hosted in IIS 7.0.
- For the sake of simplicity, lets say my service contains three methods.

  - The first method initializes the prolog engine, consults prolog source file then queries the file.
  - The second method performs another query.
  - The third method calls PlCleanup().

Method#1:

```
    public void LaunchAssessment()
    {
        Dictionary<string, string> questions = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        #region : Querying prolog using SwiPlCs
        try
        {
            if (!PlEngine.IsInitialized)
            {

                String[] param = { "-q" };
                PlEngine.Initialize(param);
                PlQuery.PlCall("consult('D:/My FYP Work/initialAssessment')");

                using (var q = new PlQuery("go(X, Y)"))
                {
                    foreach (PlQueryVariables v in q.SolutionVariables)
                    {
                        questions.Add("name", v["X"].ToString());
                        questions.Add("age", v["Y"].ToString());
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (SbsSW.SwiPlCs.Exceptions.PlException exp)
        {
            throw new FaultException<PrologFault>(new PrologFault(exp.Source), exp.MessagePl);
        }

        #endregion

        Callback.PoseQuestion(questions, ResponseType.None);
    }
```

Method#2:

```
public void DetermineAgeGroup(int age)
    {            
        //Determine age group
        string age_group = string.Empty;
        try
        {
            using (var query = new PlQuery("age_group(" + age + ", G)"))  
                {
                    foreach (PlQueryVariables v in query.SolutionVariables)
                        age_group += v["G"].ToString();
                }                
        }
        catch (SbsSW.SwiPlCs.Exceptions.PlException exp)
        {
            throw new FaultException<PrologFault>(new PrologFault(exp.Source), exp.MessagePl);
        }

        //Check whether age_group is found or not
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(age_group))
        {
            throw new FaultException<NoSolutionFoundFault>(new NoSolutionFoundFault("No solution found"), "Age specified exceeds the diagnosis range!");
        }
        else
        {
            Callback.RespondToUser(age_group, ResponseType.Age);
        }

    }
```

Method#3:

```
    public void QuitProlog()
    {
        if (PlEngine.IsInitialized)
        {
            PlEngine.PlCleanup();
        }
    }
```

The client invokes the first method just fine and a result of the first query is successfully returned. When client tries to call the second method an exception is thrown with message (attempted to read or write protected memory) which causes the application to freeze. I checked the event viewer and this is what I get:

```
    Application: w3wp.exe
    Framework Version: v4.0.30319
    Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
    Exception Info: System.AccessViolationException
```

Stack:

```
    at SbsSW.SwiPlCs.SafeNativeMethods.PL_new_term_ref()
    at SbsSW.SwiPlCs.PlQuery..ctor(System.String, System.String)
    at SbsSW.SwiPlCs.PlQuery..ctor(System.String)
    at PrologQueryService.PrologQueryService.DetermineAgeGroup(Int32)
```

Comment: At which line exactly the exception is thrown?

Comment: at the call of DetermineAgeGroup(int age) method. In this line: using (var query = new PlQuery("age_group(" + age + ", G)"))

Comment: In which instantiating mode your WCF-service work (PerCall, Single, Per-Session)?

Comment: It is set to Per-Session and ConcurrencyMode is single

Comment: Hmmm. PerSession and Single concurrency mode are correct. Try to compile all your assemblies targeting x86 platform. Sometimes such interoperability problems can be caused by compilation for x64 platform.

Comment: Also, if I were you I would try to get sources of the external library and try to dig deeper in the call stack, maybe it will unveil something. Do you have access to sources?

Comment: That is also done. Assemblies are compiled targeting x86 platform.

Comment: Try to close engine in the end of the first method and initialize it in the second again. It can shed some light on the issue. Also, keep in mind, that AccessViolation means that memory is corrupted somehow.

Comment: I will try to get the sources thanks

Comment: As I see the exception is thrown when you pass strings into the method. Strings are the pain in the ass when you interop with external programming environments such as Delphi. When you will get sources keep an eye on the declaration of the method that takes strings as parameters. Sorry, I can't give a direct solution, because the issue you have faced can be caused by thousands of reasons.

Comment: The thing is, before implementing this Client/Server architecture solution. I tested C# prolog interaction on simpler solution(Win forms application), using the same methods declared in the Wcf service and it worked perfectly fine. I don't really understand why it is not working now.

Comment: And please try to close engine as I said and reinit engine in the second method. And reply here, ok?

Comment: oh sorry. I already tried to close and reinitialize the engine. Still throwing the same exception.

Comment: Hmm, it increases the chances that the source of the issue is hosting of interoperable part on IIS. I'm not sure that IIS can correctly and automatically load your assemblies in x86. Hmmm.

Comment: @EngineerSpock ... Sorry for the late comment. I just wanted to inform you that i have managed to make it work. Although, it is not that perfect, but it might be ok for the time being. the solution was to initialize the engine, consult and query prolog, then close the engine in every method of the Wcf service.

Comment: That sounds as my proposal two comments earlier)))

Answer (score 0):

I also tried to use the interface for a .NET project.

Looking in the [official repository](https://github.com/SWI-Prolog/contrib-swiplcs) of the CSharp interface to SWI-Prolog I noticed that the project is very old and the latest updates do not seem included in the binaries available in the download page of the official website.

Then I did the following steps:

- The contrib repository dedicated to .NET indicates that the compatible SWI-Prolog version (at the time of writing) is "8.0.3-1" (look in the [README file](https://github.com/SWI-Prolog/contrib-swiplcs/blob/master/README)).
  -> Then I uninstalled from my computer the latest stable and installed the indicated one. I got it from the full list of downloads of the old versions at this [link](https://www.swi-prolog.org/download/stable?show=all).
- I cloned the *SWI-Prolog/contrib-swiplcs* repository, unloaded the incompatible projects from the solution, in my case, since I don't use Visual Studio.
  -> I set the target framework to Net Framework 4.8 and recompiled it (you can also do this with standard NET). Beware of some pragma directives defined in the old project file (For example I re-defined *_PL_X64* variable via code.
- I brought the main unit test methods into a new project with xUnit wiht the appropriate changes.
- I set the target to x64, recompiled and rebuilt the tests and the "hello world" example.

It worked!
I was able to use SWI-Prolog both for Net 4.8 and in other Net Core applications (if you make the needed changes in order to target the Net Standard). You should not have any problem in both cases).

This is my [fork](https://github.com/sandhaka/contrib-swiplcs) as a preliminary example.

Finally, I can load a *.pl Prolog file with a program in my C# application and use it to evaluate some business logic rules (example with boolean answer [Permitted/Not-Permitted]):

```
[Fact]
public void ShouldLoadAProgramAndUseIt()
{
    var pathValues = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("PATH");
    pathValues += @";C:\Program Files\swipl\bin";
    Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("PATH", pathValues);

    // Positioning to project folder
    var currentDirectory = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory().Split('\\').ToList();
    currentDirectory.RemoveAll(r => currentDirectory.ToArray().Reverse().Take(3).Contains(r));
    var basePath = currentDirectory.Aggregate((c1, c2) => $"{c1}\\{c2}");
    
    var filePath = $"{basePath}\\prolog_examples\\exec_checker.pl";
    
    String[] param = { "-q", "-f", filePath };
    PlEngine.Initialize(param);
    try
    {
        var query = "exutable('2020-08-15',[('monthly', ['2019-12-30', '2020-03-10'])])";
        _testOutputHelper.WriteLine($"Query: {query}");
        
        using (var q = new PlQuery(query))
        {
            var booleanAnswer = q.NextSolution();
            _testOutputHelper.WriteLine($"Answer: {booleanAnswer}");
            Assert.True(booleanAnswer);
        }

        query = "exutable('2020-08-15',[('daily', ['2019-12-30', '2020-08-15'])])";
        _testOutputHelper.WriteLine($"Query: {query}");
        
        using (var q = new PlQuery(query))
        {
            var booleanAnswer = q.NextSolution();
            _testOutputHelper.WriteLine($"Answer: {booleanAnswer}");
            Assert.False(booleanAnswer);
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        PlEngine.PlCleanup();
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try to close engine in the end of the first method and initialize it in the second again.

You can check this as the answer to the question unless you object.

Comment: Is "try" considered to be an answer? Have you tried yourself? While closing and reopening is a workaround that seems to work (see comments above), is there also a real solution that might not involve closing and reopening? Is it possible to report a bug somewhere?